# Redirecting Facebook app back to origin

Tags: ios, facebook, pinterest, applinks

I've been trying to go with Applink protocol provide linkback referal from Facebook to original app. The way I've contructed destination link is:

```
fb://profile/123456?al_applink_data=<encoded_json>
```

where  is url encded string:

```
{"target_url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com/123456","referer_app_link":{"url":"myawesomeapp:\/\/member\/bojan-babic","app_name":"MyAwesomeApp"}}
```

In app itself this is opened in following manner:

```
    let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    let targetUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: targetUrlString)!
    application.openURL(targetUrl)
```

Outcome is that myawesome opens native iOS app, but I do not see "Touch to get back to MyAwesomeApp" header within Facebook App.

What would be proper process to achieve link back to original app? 
Note: I've tried same approach with Pinterest iOS app as well